# Splitting wordpress posts into multiple pages (CSS styling)

Tags: css, wordpress, split

Most of my blog posts are too long and i divide them into 3-4 parts using `<!--nextpage-->`

Normally it shows only post numbers 1 2 3 4...

I want to style (small boxes) them using CSS but i don't know how to do it.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I did not try anything.

Comment: Check for the tag and class those pagination numbers are marked with to define CSS with padding and background attributes to show them as boxes.

Comment: Look at this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-pagination-styles

Answer (score 1):

You can go here ["Styling Page Links"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links) guide on wordpress